# Merge arrays into a dictionary upon a criteria?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have two arrays:

```
First array = ["lines","lines","lines","lines"]
Second array = ["one","two","","three","four","","five","six","","seven","eight"]
```

I want to merge them into a dictionary with a nested array:

```
Dict = ["lines":["one","two"],"lines":["three","four"],"lines":["five","six"],"lines":["seven","eight"]]
```

Basically values from the second array should be split due to blank space criteria ("") and assigned as separate array objects inside a dictionary.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary. Would a two-level array suffice? `[["one","two"], ["three","four"], ["five","six"], ["seven","eight"]]`

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Yes, i believe it would.

Comment: just use a for loop through the first array and then nest a while do loop for the second set of values, with forward counter through the second array "while array2[counter] != """ do blah blah this is pseudo code, but you get the idea

Comment: thank you! i'll be trying out the code soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
let array2 = ["one","two","","three","four","","five","six","","seven","eight"] 
var splittedArray = array2.split { $0 == "" }
```

Result from Playground:
[image]

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I've used Xcode 7 iOS 9

Comment: @EricD. Thanks, added note :)

Answer (score 0):

**So much for elegance, but this works exactly like you want it:**

```
var First  = ["lines","lines","lines","lines"]
var Second  = ["one","two","","three","four","","five","six","","seven","eight"]

var counter = 0
var counters = 0
var counterss = 0
var response = NSMutableArray(capacity: First.count)

for obj in First {
    var re = NSMutableArray()
    while counterss != Second.count-1 && Second[counterss] != ""  {
        if (counterss < (Second.count)) {
            re[counters] = Second[counterss]
            counterss = counterss + 1
            counters = counters + 1
        }
    }
    if Second[counterss] == "" {
        counterss = counterss + 1
    }
    if counterss == (Second.count-1) {
        re[counters] = Second.last!
    }
    counters = 0
    response[counter] = [First[counter],re]
    counter = counter + 1
}
println("heres the final array \(response)")
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**heres the solution with the required dictionary objects that are inside the main array:**

```
var First  = ["lines","lines","lines","lines"]
var Second  = ["one","two","","three","four","","five","six","","seven","eight"]

var counter = 0
var counters = 0
var counterss = 0
var response = NSMutableArray(capacity: First.count)

for obj in First {
    var re = NSMutableArray()
    while counterss != Second.count-1 && Second[counterss] != ""  {
        if (counterss < (Second.count)) {
            re[counters] = Second[counterss]
            counterss = counterss + 1
            counters = counters + 1
        }
    }
    if Second[counterss] == "" {
        counterss = counterss + 1
    }
    if counterss == (Second.count-1) {
        re[counters] = Second.last!
    }
    counters = 0
    var ss = [First[counter] : re] as Dictionary
    response[counter] = ss
    counter = counter + 1
}
println("heres the final array \(response)")
```

**and here's the final, a dictionary of dictionaries:**

```
var First  = ["lines","lines","lines","lines"]
var Second  = ["one","two","","three","four","","five","six","","seven","eight"]

var counter = 0
var counters = 0
var counterss = 0
var response = NSMutableDictionary(capacity: First.count)

for obj in First {
    var re = NSMutableArray()
    while counterss != Second.count-1 && Second[counterss] != ""  {
        if (counterss < (Second.count)) {
            re[counters] = Second[counterss]
            counterss = counterss + 1
            counters = counters + 1
        }
    }
    if Second[counterss] == "" {
        counterss = counterss + 1
    }
    if counterss == (Second.count-1) {
        re[counters] = Second.last!
    }
    counters = 0
    var ss = [First[counter] : re] as Dictionary
    response[counter] = ss
    counter = counter + 1
}
println("heres the final array \(response)")
```

It's not an ordered dictionary by dictionary index, but the indexes match the information you wanted:

[image]

On yeah, and this is a dictionary of dictionaries that contain a "name" and "an array" in each dictionary, just as asked for.

Comment: sorry, had to update again, this now works, as it should

Comment: and, this includes the "lines" value from the first array

Comment: and it works for any size of arrays so if you change the arrays with breaks and then change the amount of "lines" this still works

Answer (score -1):

This'll do it:

```
for value in firstArray {
    if value == "" {
        // Add a blank subarray whenever we find an empty string.
        combinedArray.append([String]())
    } else if combinedArray.count == 0 {
        combinedArray.append([value])
    } else {
        // Append the value to the last subarray.
        combinedArray[combinedArray.count - 1].append(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that your example skips the first item. Result: `[[two], [three, four], [five, six], [seven, eight]]`.

Comment: I also tried it with `filter()` and `reduce()`, but that code was too ugly.